# Please consider following the Sanskrit proposal

Tags: discussion

We know [How important Sanskrit is](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2275/277). We also have [one closed QA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9676/277) that talks about learning Sanskrit.

I believe many of users of this community would be interested in Sanskrit site proposal and there is a Sanskrit language proposal on Area51 live! Do please consider following it.

Here is the link:

[image]

We also need hands to define the scope and adding more questions and/or other contributions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we make it a featured post?

Comment: Featured tag is for those posts which help our community. This is not about Hinduism Stack Exchange. Upvoting and getting into hot posts is a bonus. Featured tag is not required to this. It would look like abuse of tool and mod personally advocating the proposal. Those who are interested will follow. Extra push is not needed.

Comment: I am not sure how feature tag works but I think it should be fine if the community together thinks they should feature this or any other post.

Comment: Yesterday I followed the proposal by tapping on "follow it" but strangely my name is not shown among the followers. It shd show among recent followers but not shown.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for following. You might have followed using another email id (just a guess). If you are sure about this, then try asking on Area51 meta.

Comment: @Mr_Green See from [this link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/177271/rickross?tab=followed) that I'm actually following the proposal. I can see the "unfollow" option but strangely my userid is not shown among the recent followers list.